# How do I save an image on disk and the images path on mongodb with multer?

Tags: mongodb, express, multer, mern

So far I managed to make an image to be uploaded on mongo, but I cant make it to get saved on disk.

**React component**

```
const handleUploadPhoto = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const uploads = photos.map(async photo => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('photo', photo);

        await axios.post(
            `${baseUrl}/api/photo/upload/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUser'))._id}`,
            formData,
            { headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }},
        );
    });
};
```

**Upload route with multer setup**:

```
const FILE_PATH = 'uploads';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, FILE_PATH),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const newFileName = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}-${file.originalname.split('.')[0]}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, newFileName);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    fileFilter (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpeg\jpg\png)$/)) {
            cb(new Error('Only upload jpg and png files.'));
        }

        cb(undefined, true);
    }
});

router.post('/upload/:userid', upload.single('photo'), uploadPhoto);
```

**And the controller**:

```
const { name, data, mimetype } = req.files.photo;

 User
    .findById(req.params.userid)
    .exec((error, user) => {
        if (error || !user) return res.status(404).json({ message: error.message, });

        const newPhoto = new Photo({
            photo: {
                mimetype,
                data,
                path: `${__dirname}/uploads/${name}`,
                name,
            },
            owner: user._id,
        });

        newPhoto.save((error, photo) => {
            if (error) return res.status(401).json({ message: error, });

            user.photos.push(newPhoto._id);
            user.save();

            return res.status(201).json({
                message: `Image created`,
                path: photo.path,
            });
        });
    });
```

So, as you can see, I am saving the data as Buffer in mongodb and I want to actually save the image on disk and only the name, mymetype and the path(location on disk) of the image on mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You are using `upload.single()` to get the uploaded file

```js
router.post('/upload/:userid', upload.single('photo'), uploadPhoto);
```

and `upload.single()` is gonna attach the file to `req.file` not `req.files`. which, your getting the uploaded file using `req.files`, which is used to upload multiple files:

```js
const { name, data, mimetype } = req.files.photo;
```

Second: `__dirname` get the path of the current file not the current working directory, [for more info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-__dirname-and-in-node-js/) , so you should not use `__dirname`, instead use `./`. So I am assuming your actually saving the file to a different directory but using the wrong path to save in Mongo.

Third: You are using `multer.diskStorage` which automatically saves the file to disk, and because you are using `diskStorage` you don't have access to the `buffer` according to [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information). read the docs cause apparently you are using the wrong properties of uploaded files in here:

```js
const { name, data, mimetype } = req.files.photo;
```

You got to replace it with:

```js
const { filename, mimetype } = req.file; // don't have access to buffer in diskStorage
```

Comment: Yes mate, nice explanation. It works now. Thank you.